# how to move an image in objective c

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiimageview, uiimage

I want to move image to another x,y position. I try this code but not work it crash after 3 seconds. The error is: 2012-01-17 12:40:47.213 YapiKrediDemo[1986:207] -[Sozlesme moveImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6c316c0.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

image1=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"GirisButton.png"]];

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 3
                                 target: self
                               selector:@selector(moveImage:)
                               userInfo: nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void) moveImage
{
//[image1 setCenter: CGPointMake(634, 126)];
CGPoint pointOne=CGPointMake(634, 126);
image1.center=pointOne;
}
```

How can I solve ?

Comment: you should write your moveImage method prototype on your .h file, thats your problem.

Comment: ^ Thats not true. He doesn't HAVE to define selectors in the H file. both answers below described why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector is `@selector(moveImage)`. No `:` at the end. Or you have to add a parameter to the moveImage method. That's what you should do. `- (void)moveImage:(NSTimer*)timer`

Comment: I try with this @selector(moveImage) and - (void)moveImage:(NSTimer*)timer, but I got error 2012-01-17 14:01:11.417 YapiKrediDemo[2147:207] -[Sozlesme moveImage]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6e07540

Comment: no sry you miss understood me. If you use `- (void)moveImage:(NSTimer*)timer` you have to use `@selector(moveImage:)`

Answer (score 2):

Your selector needs to be `@selector(moveImage)` without the colon. 
`moveImage:` would mean a parameter is expected, while your method delceration below doesn't accept any parameters.

You could also just change the frame.

```cpp
 CGRect myFrame = image1.frame;
 myFrame.origin.x = 634;
 myFrame.origin.y = 126;
 image1.frame = myFrame;
```

Comment: I try this way also, but still I get error 2012-01-17 13:57:55.846 YapiKrediDemo[2058:207] -[Sozlesme moveImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a240c0